# C# :remove one line in a Txt file

Tags: c#

i want to remove one line in a txt file after i've gotten the data with StreamReader.WriteLine().
but i cannot  get any useful reference for the web. 
somebody tell me that i can do it with the Repalce() method .but i dont think its efficent.
can anyone tell me how to resolve it. thanks!

Comment: What is the reason for concerning it as unefficient method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't remove something in the middle of a file. You either have to rewrite everything from that point on, or simply rewrite the whole file. And if you are using StreamReader/StreamWriter, then you don't have any access to file position, so your only choice is to rewrite the whole file.

Here is an example method on how to do it.

```
    public static void RemoveLines(Predicate<string> removeFunction,string file){
        string line, tempFile = null;
        try{
            tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(tempFile,false,sr.CurrentEncoding))
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    if (!removeFunction(line)) sw.WriteLine(line);
            File.Delete(file);
            File.Move(tempFile, file);
        }finally{
            if(tempFile != null && File.Exists(tempFile))
                File.Delete(tempFile);
        }
    }
```

Used like this

```
RemoveLines(line=>line.Length==10,"test.txt")
```

it removes all the lines with a length of 10 characters, and uses a temp file to minimize the risks involved. Of course, if you want something shorter you could do something like this.

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName,File.ReadAllLines(fileName).Where(line => line.Length != 10))
```

Requires more working memory, and you should probably do the tempfile/move trick to hedge against a computer crash causing a corrupt file. But it is code that is compact and easy to understand.